# How can I save MultiDigraph in graphml format?

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking

I'm using the python package `networkx` and have a `MultiDigraph`which I want to save it in graphml format to use it in another software for my further analysis. I have sone nodes and edges attributes also.

I used the bellow command but it didn't work. It seems this command doesn't work for `MultiDigraph`.

```
nx.write_graphml(G, 'C:\\hm\\HMGraph.gml')
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
nx.write_graphml(G, 'C:\\hm\\HMGraph.gml')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-e35c8921ea4a>", line 1, in <module>
    nx.write_graphml(G, 'C:\\hm\\HMGraph.gml')

  File "<decorator-gen-809>", line 2, in write_graphml_lxml

  File "C:\Users\xparve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 239, in _open_file
    result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\xparve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 153, in write_graphml_lxml
    writer = GraphMLWriterLxml(

  File "C:\Users\xparve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 664, in __init__
    self.add_graph_element(graph)

  File "C:\Users\xparve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 714, in add_graph_element
    T = self.xml_type[self.attr_type(k, "edge", v)]

KeyError: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your attributes is of type [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). However, as you can see from the implementation of `networkx` only the following types are supported (see `GraphML` class [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/readwrite/graphml.html))

```
        types = [
            (int, "integer"),  # for Gephi GraphML bug
            (str, "yfiles"),
            (str, "string"),
            (int, "int"),
            (int, "long"),
            (float, "float"),
            (float, "double"),
            (bool, "boolean"),
        ]
```

So you need to manually replace the `datetime` objects by e.g. creating string representations.